# JQuery Plugin Not Loading from Local Repository

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flask, jinja2

I am trying to make a Tree Table using https://supwisdom.github.io/bootstrap-treefy/ within a Flask app.
I've downloaded the js files because it seems this plugin isn't available via api and the file structure looks like this (with many other files I'm choosing not to type out below):

- app

  - static

    - css
    - js

      - bootstrap-treefy.js
      - bootstrap-treefy.min.js
  - templates

    - tree.html

My table is formatted exactly as the example on the above link (I've even tested with the exact table copy/pasted), however, I keep getting the following error: 
`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).treeFy is not a function`

My tree.html file looks like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/../static/js/bootstrap-treefy.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="/../static/js/bootstrap-treefy.min.js"></script>

    {{ html_tree | safe }}

    <script  type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#table").treeFy({
                treeColumn: 1
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

{% endblock %}
```

My IntelliJ IDE seems to recognize treeFy as a function and even lets me middle click to redirect to it in my file structure, but it doesn't seem to be being recognized when called in the script. Inspecting the page Sources in Chrome it also shows those .js files in the structure and I'm not getting a 404 when referencing them in my scripts at the start of the body, so I'm at a loss for why it's not recognizing the call to treeFy. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `src="/../` is nonsense because you can't start at the root and then go up another level. The root is the top. The browser is going to discard the `../` bit.

Comment: You haven't told us how your Flask server is configured to serve static files. We've no idea what (if any) URL has been given to the files in the `static` directory.

Comment: `<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"` is HTML 4.01 Transitional. We've had HTML 5 for over a decade. Get rid of the attributes. They don't do anything except provide an opportunity for you to make a typo that breaks the scripts.

Comment: The flask app is initialized with ```app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="/static")``` and this ```__init__.py``` file is located in the app directory. I know the Flask Server is initialized to serve static files correctly because it has no problem reaching any other file within my static directory.

Comment: Why are you hand crafting a URL instead of following [the instructions](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/#static-files)

Comment: Does base.html load jQuery too?

Comment: I've updated it to use ```url_for```, I was just trying to implement something quickly for testing purposes and so used exact URL. Unfortunately with the update, it's still showing the same error.
```base.html``` does load jQuery, but I've commented that out and even not included base.html and still the same error.

Comment: Okay I was playing around with eliminating the base.html file again and it works (there must have been some conflicting jQuery in that file as you suggested). I mistakenly thought eliminating ```{% extends "base.html" %}``` would suffice, but what I didn't do was add back the ```<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"> </html>``` so the template was not working correctly. Thank you @Quentin!